# win32 read java preference from c++ code

Tags: java, c++, windows, utf-8, preferences

One of our program writes program information(window title, memory etc) in Java Preferences. On windows this is available under  registry.  How can I read the values written by Java program using c (or c++).

Looks like API I should use is RegGetValue. Is this guaranteed to work on Windows XP 32 bit?

The String written by java is UTF-8 encoded. How do I read such strings in windows (win32 or vc++)

Cheers,
Jayan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug into this a bit.  RegGetValue() is a new registry call that takes care of some underlying nastiness of the traditional way of querying the registry (RegQueryValueEx).  There's some good info about the difference here: http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2006/01/12/512115.aspx

If you need backwards compatibility, RegGetValue() isn't going to work, so you should be using RegQueryValueEx to read data from the registry.

And now on to what I think is the real question:

1. What do you get back when you use RegQueryValueEx() ?
2. How do you know that the values stored in the registry are in utf-8 encoding?  Is it stored as a byte array in the registry, or as a REG_SZ?
3. Have you looked at the value using regedit?  What do you see?

So if the question is how to convert a UTF-8 encoded string to an ascii null terminated string, then you should probably change the title of your question.  For reference, I found this library that may be of use:

http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net

When I tried the link a few minutes ago, the server timed out - probably SF maintenance going on.

But I would suggest that you make real sure that the values in the registry aren't stored as REG_SZ entries already.

Comment: What makes you think RegGetValue works on Windows XP?  Did you test it yourself?  On which service pack?  The MSDN documentation states that Vista or XP SP1 is required.

Comment: fair enough - I thought the OP meant to write RegQueryValue() - I've updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`RegGetValue` is a newer API.  If you want your program to work on XP 32-bit (actually back before Windows 2000) use [RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911(v=VS.85).aspx)

A UTF-8 string is NUL-terminated just like any single-byte ASCII string.  However you might be interested in converting it to UTF-16.  For that you'd want to use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072(VS.85).aspx), setting CodePage to `CP_UTF8`.  From UTF-16 you can convert to any other code page using [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130(v=VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the registry in C++, you may be interested in the [CRegKey ATL class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5eccs806%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).